# My loop boolean is not compiling

Tags: java, loops, boolean, incompatibletypeerror

I need this method to go through my ArrayList myZip, find whether or not there is an integer in there that matches int zip, then go and find the ZipCode that is equal to intZip; if there is no match then return null.

```
public ZipCode findZip(int zip) {
    for (int i = 0; i < myZips.size(); i++) {
        if (zip == myZips.get(i)) 
            return myZips.get(i);}
        return null;
}
```

Any ideas?

Here's the ZipCode Class:

```
public class ZipCode {

    private int zipCode;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;


    public ZipCode(int pZip) {
        zipCode   = pZip;
        city      = "UNKOWN";
        state     = "ST";
        latitude  = 0.0;
        longitude = 0.0;
    }

    public ZipCode (int pZip, String pCity, String pState, double pLat, double pLon) {
        zipCode   = pZip;
        city      = pCity;
        state     = pState;
        latitude  = pLat;
        longitude = pLon;

    }

    public void setZipCode(int zipCode){
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public void setCity (String city){
        this.city = city;
    }

    public void setState (String state){
        this.state = state;
    }

    public void setLatitude (double latitude){
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude (double longitude){
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public int getZipCode (){
        return zipCode;
    }

    public String getCity (){
        return city;
    }

    public String getState(){
        return state;
    }

    public double getLatitude(){
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude(){
        return longitude;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return city + ", " + state + zipCode;
}
}
```

I really just need to know how to make the findZip method return the ZipCode that is the same as int zip.

This is eventually going to pull from a file.txt that has addresses formatted like this:
94594, MerryVille, WA, Longitude, Latitude

Comment: What do you think `"null"` is? What do you think `=` does in `zip = myZips.get(i)`?

Comment: I am sorry if not, but this almost feels like a troll question. Almost every line of that code contains some error.

Comment: What is the type of `myZips` ?

Comment: but you're trying to return an Integer entry from that, when the function spec says you're returning a `ZipCode` ?!

Comment: @PavelHoral yup, never seen so many WTFs in so few lines of code

Comment: What is the type `ZipCode` ? Is it defined somewhere? does `myZips` contain ZipCode's?

Comment: @Alnitak I'm a bit new to this, as in I started coding on and off about 3 months ago.

Comment: @David +1 to you for not getting discouraged by all the negativity, answering questions and updating your code when asked. _I think_ my answer is close to what you want, if not, feel free to leave me a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want something like this.

```
List<ZipCode> myZips = // create all ZipCode's somehow

public ZipCode findZip(int zip){

    //look at all zips
    for(ZipCode zipCode : myZips){

        //if we find one that matches the one we want, return it
        if(zipCode.getZipCode() == zip){
            return zipCode;
        }
    }

    // we checked all our zip's and couldn't find this one
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Lol, I misread my teacher's notes as requiring me to have an ArrayList of Integers instead of one of Zipcodes, and have spent an hour staring at my screen doing jack shit because of it.

Comment: lol, I fixed OP's code and I get downvoted for it... SO makes me laugh sometimes

Answer (score 2):

Use == in your of condition.

Also, no need for the doubke-quotes around null.

Finally, 'return null' needs to be outside of your for loop. Otherwise, on the first non-match, it will return null. You want to wait for the whole loop (all zips) to be compared before returning null. On a match, you can return right away.

Comment: The downvoter should put a comment. I see nothing wrong in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
if (zip = myZips.get(i))
```

You should use

`if (zip == myZips.get(i))`

Answer (score 0):

Errasing the errors with quations around `null`, changing the `if` to a comparision, and moving the `else` to outside of the `for` will give us this.

```
public ZipCode findZip (int zip) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= myZips.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (zip == myZips.get(i)) {
            return myZips.get(i);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

However, that still won't do it I am going to take a guess at. The reason for it is the `int` to `ZipCode` comparrison now.

Answer (score -1):

In your if statement, you're attempting to compare an int to a, presumably, ZipCode. Your method declaration should instead be

```
public ZipCode findZip(ZipCode zip){
  for (int i = 0; i <= myZips.size() - 1; i++)
  if (zip == myZips.get(i)) 
    return myZips.get(i);
  else
    return "null";
```

You would then of course need to pass in a ZipCode to your method, rather than an int

Comment: @JackmeriusTacktheritrix that's what I get for copy-pasting. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke.  It's supposed to be a user entered 5 digit integer, not a zipcode.

Comment: Then you can't just compare `ZipCode` and `int` with `==`. You should post the code for `ZipCode` so we have more to work with.

Comment: @JackmeriusTacktheritrix well you can try, but it won't work out very well ;)

Answer (score -1):

Couple of things :

1) Below comparison (if you are tying to compare) is wrong

```
 if (zip = myZips.get(i))
```

Correct way should be

```
 if (zip == myZips.get(i))
```

2) Why are you returning from the for loop ? Shouldn't you be processing the whole array list and then return the value in an appropriate manner

3) Return type of your function is ZipCode, not sure how "null" is going to work for you.

Comment: re: 2 - no, in cases like this you explicitly _should_ jump out of the loop, otherwise you're wasting cycles when you already known the answer

Comment: re: 3 - I know the answer, but why? How is `null` different from `"null"` ?