# Getting an (int,int) parameter to accept a (int, array) input

Tags: java

Is there any way to convert a ZipCode from my ArrayList myZips into an Integer so it can work as a parameter of my distance method?

ZipCode class:

```
public class ZipCode
{
    private int zipCode;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;

    public ZipCode(int pZip)
    {
        zipCode   = pZip;
        city      = "UNKOWN";
        state     = "ST";
        latitude  = 0.0;
        longitude = 0.0;
    }

    public ZipCode(int pZip, String pCity, String pState, double pLat, double pLon)
    {
        zipCode   = pZip;
        city      = pCity;
        state     = pState;
        latitude  = pLat;
        longitude = pLon;

    }

    public void setZipCode(int zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public int getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public String getState() {
    return state;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return city + ", " + state + zipCode;
    }
}


public class ZipCodeDatabase {

    private ArrayList<ZipCode> myZips;

public ZipCodeDatabase()
{
    myZips = new ArrayList<ZipCode>();
}

public ZipCode findZip(int zip){
    for(ZipCode zipCode : myZips){

        if(zipCode.getZipCode() == zip){
            return zipCode;
        }
    }

    return null;

}

public double distance(int zip1, int zip2) {
    int EARTH_RADIUS = 3959;
    if (findZip(zip1) != null && findZip(zip2) != null) {
        ZipCode z1 = new ZipCode(zip1);
        ZipCode z2 = new ZipCode(zip2);
        double lat1  = Math.toRadians(z1.getLatitude());
        double long1 = Math.toRadians(z1.getLongitude());
        double lat2  = Math.toRadians(z2.getLatitude());
        double long2 = Math.toRadians(z2.getLongitude());

        double p1 = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(long1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(long2);       
        double p2 = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(long1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(long2);         
        double p3 = Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2);         
        double distance = Math.acos(p1+p2+p3) * EARTH_RADIUS;
        int distance1 = (int)Math.round(distance);
        return distance1;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
public ArrayList <ZipCode> withinRadius(int pZip, int pRadius){
    ArrayList<ZipCode> zips = new ArrayList<ZipCode> ();
    if (findZip(pZip) != null){
        for (int i = 0; i < myZips.size(); i++){
            if (distance(pZip, myZips.get(i)) <= pRadius) //the trouble is here, how can I convert the myZips.get(I) into the relevant 5 digit integer .
            zips.add(pZip);
        }
    }
    return zips;
}
```

}

I know this is a very specialized and basic question but I'm new to java and can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Maybe `Integer.parseInt(myZips[i])`?

Comment: What's the `ZipCode` class like?

Comment: I'd stick with ZipCode and change the int params to ZipCode instead. Ints may work where you live, but over here, we have both letters and numbers in zipcodes.

Comment: It says it requires an array but found an ArrayList instead.

Comment: @Kenney I'm pulling from a bank of Zips that all are numbers only.

Comment: Isn't `findZip` literally just doing `myZips.contains(zip)` ? Except returning the object instead of true/false.

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah, pretty much :P

Comment: @Zizouz212 just added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the reasoning behind having `findZip` because I think you are doing more look-ups than you need, but anyways, you were close, just needed to save a reference to the `ZipCode` you found from `findZip` and call `getZipCode()` in the `distance` method.

```
public static final int EARTH_RADIUS = 3959; // Move constants out of methods

public ZipCode findZip(int zip){
    for(ZipCode zipCode : myZips){
        if(zipCode.getZipCode() == zip){
            return zipCode;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public int distance(int zip1, int zip2){
    // save these references so you can use them later
    ZipCode z1 = findZip(zip1);
    ZipCode z2 = findZip(zip2);

    if(z1 != null && z2 != null) {
        double lat1  = Math.toRadians(z1.getLatitude());
        double long1 = Math.toRadians(z1.getLongitude());
        double lat2  = Math.toRadians(z2.getLatitude());
        double long2 = Math.toRadians(z2.getLongitude());

        double p1 = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(long1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(long2);       
        double p2 = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(long1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(long2);         
        double p3 = Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2);         

        double distance = Math.acos(p1+p2+p3) * EARTH_RADIUS;
        return (int)Math.round(distance);
    }
    else return -1;
}

public ArrayList <ZipCode> withinRadius(int pZip, int pRadius){
    ZipCode zip = findZip(pZip); // save this reference to calculate the distances

    ArrayList<ZipCode> zips = new ArrayList<ZipCode> ();
    if (zip != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myZips.size(); i++) {
            ZipCode z = myZips.get(i); // or use a for-each loop like in findZip
            if (distance(zip.getZipCode(), z.getZipCode()) <= pRadius) {
                zips.add(z);
            }
        }
    }
    return zips;
}
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to chance method parameters (for some god awful reason).  Also I tried something like this before and it gave me a Static context error.

Comment: @David - Then how are you supposed to get the longitude and latitude within the `distance` method if you are just given integers? Use `findZip`?

Comment: These are the instructions I was given:  public int distance(int zip1, int zip2) - return the distance in miles between two zip codes. See the information at the end of this document for calculating the distance. Call your findZip()method rather than searching within this method. If either of the zip codes do not exist, return -1.  Note, you will need to convert the solution to an integer before returning.

Comment: The information in the back was just the equations at the bottom of the method

Comment: @David, instructions say `public int distance(...)`, your code has `public double distance(...)`

Comment: Just noticed that myself, too. Thanks @jb.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote that [findZip method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33661150/my-loop-boolean-is-not-compiling/33661713#33661713)! :)

I'm guessing all you need is this if you only have two zips to look at.

```
ZipCode zip1 = myZips.get(0);
ZipCode zip2 = myZips.get(1);
double d = distance(zip1.getZipCode(), zip2.getZipCode());
```

If you want to convert your entire ZipCode list, you can do this

```
List<Integer> zipCodeInts = new ArrayList<>(myZips.size());
for(ZipCode zipCode : myZips){
    zipCodeInts.add(zipCode.getZipCode());
}
// now use zipCodeInts somehow
```

Side note, you can save those two `new`'s. Instead of doing this:

```
if (findZip(zip1) != null && findZip(zip2) != null) {
    ZipCode z1 = new ZipCode(zip1);
    ZipCode z2 = new ZipCode(zip2);
    // do stuff
}
```

You can do this

```
ZipCode z1 = findZip(zip1);
ZipCode z2 = findZip(zip2);

if(z1 != null && z2 != null) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Always nice to know your code is being used for something :D

Comment: @jb Yeah it is.  I'll make sure I don't use it in my final version.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the `int` that holds the zip code from the class:

```
ZipCodeDatabase.distance(myZipCode.getZipCode(), yourZipCode.getZipCode());
```